# Una expresión regular para caracteres alfanuméricos menos salto de linea

Tags: xml, regex

Actualmente tengo la siguiente expresión regular:

```
^[^\n][\w\W][^\n]{1,5}$
```

La cual exceptua los saltos de linea pero cuando escribo

```
s
d
```

me toma un match y no deberia. Ademas el rango de caracteres de 1 a 5 no lo esta tomando como es, toma apartir de 2 caracteres y no de 1.

Por favor, alguien que me ayude hacer una expresión regular que tome todos los caracteres alfanuméricos incluyendo simbolos menos saltos de linea.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que esta expresion satisface lo que deseas

```
^[\w\W][^\n]{0,5}$
```

Sería mejor si explicas que s lo que realmente deseas lograr con tu expresión.

Testeado en [Regexr](https://regexr.com/)

Answer (score 0):

A menos que utilices el modificador `s`, el `.` debería encontrar cualquier caracter excepto saltos de líneas. Así que puedes utilizarlo en lugar de `[^\n]`. Además la clase `[\w\W]` te está buscando cualquier cosa (incluídos saltos de línea) porque estás agregando a la clase: cualquier cosa tipo palabra y lo opuesto, con lo que busca cualquier cosa (también saltos de línea)

Yo probaría con:

`^.{1,5}$`

https://regex101.com/r/RJCdgJ/1/

Si además quisieras evitar los espacios al principio y al final de la línea podrías hacerlo con

`^\s*.{1,5}\s*$`

Disculpa si no he entendido el enunciado correctamente. Si es el caso agradecería un par de ejemplos de entrada vs resultado esperado.